# Super User requires external JavaScript from another domain.... Why?

Tags: javascript, adblock

I use NoScript which is a selective ad-blocker.   Very recently Superuser and other stack exchange sites started claiming that it requires external Javascript to work (at the top) - but the only non-listed sites are ad sites.

Is there a way to get WYSIWIG editing, finding tags and submitting working without enabling advert servers and inter-site tracking?

Comment: Which domain is it pulling from it might simply be from StackExchange

Comment: there's a full listing of the external sites SE uses somewhere on MSE....

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this problem was only happening on my home computer, even though I run similar software elsewhere.

Uninstalling and reinstalling noscript fixed the problem - so I expect there was some kind of corruption related to its database.